# invalid anonymous type member declarator during join two datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, anonymous

I try to do the following join :

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 on  new { 
                     t1.["main_code"], 
                     t1["year"]} 
                     equals new { 
                         t2["dep_code"], 
                         t2["dep_year"] }
                         select new { 
                             emp_name = t1["name"], 
                             bonus_desc = t1["bonus_desc"],
                             dep_name = t2["dep_name"] };
```

but I face the following build error!!

> invalid anonymous type member declarator

Comment: is bonus_desc exists in your table dt1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name properties of anonymous type of `join` :

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 on  new { PropertyA= t1["main_code"], PropertyB=t1["year"]} equals new { PropertyA=t2["dep_code"], PropertyB=t2["dep_year"] }
                 select new { emp_name = t1["name"], bonus_desc = t1["bonus_desc"],dep_name = t2["dep_name"] };
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitely name your properties, for example:

```
var collection = 
    from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
    join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
    on new { code = t1["main_code"], year = t1["year"] } equals 
       new { code = t2["dep_code"], year = t2["dep_year"] }
    select new { emp_name = t1["name"], bonus_desc = t1["bonus_desc"] /* ... */};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var collection = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 on  new { field1 = t1.["main_code"], field2 = t1["year"]} equals new { field1 = t2["dep_code"], field2 = t2["dep_year"] }
                 select new { emp_name = t1["name"], bonus_desc = t1["bonus_desc"],dep_name = t2["dep_name"] };
```